# Hide items by class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show-hide

I have a list of cities that host locations around the world. I want to create a drop-down filter that sorts the locations according to their continent. Here is the php part of the filter

```
...
<div>
    <label for="filt_country">Show:</label>
    <select id="filt_country">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">All Countries</option>
        <option value="1">Restuarant Locations</option>
        <optgroup label="Meetings By County ">
            <option value="2">Africa</option>
            <option value="3">Antartica</option>
            <option value="4">Asia</option>
            <option value="5">Europe</option>
            <option value="6">NAmerica</option>
            <option value="7">SAmerica</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>

<article class="location">
  <div class="body_location Europe Twenty">
    <p class="location_city">
      <span class="capital">Tbilisi</span>
      <span class="Country">Georgia</span>
    </p>
    <div class="country_descr">
      <h3 class="country_anthem">Tavisupleba</h3>
      <p><strong>Writer: </strong>David Magradze</p>
      <p><strong>Music: </strong>Zachary Paliashvili/Ioseb Kechakmadze</p>
      <p></p>
  </div>
</article>
...
```

and this is the Javascript that shows or hide the elements according to their country

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#country-filter').on('change', function() {
        if ( this.value == '0') {
            $(".Africa").show();
            $(".Antartica").show();
            $(".Asia").show();
            $(".Europe").show();
            $(".NAmerica").show();
            $(".Oceania").show();
            $(".SAmerica").show();
        }
        else ( this.value == '2') {
            $(".Africa").show();
            $(".Antartica").hide();
            $(".Asia").hide();
            $(".Europe").hide();
            $(".NAmerica").hide();
            $(".Oceania").hide();
            $(".SAmerica").hide();
        }
        else ( this.value == '3') {
            $(".Africa").show();
            $(".Antartica").hide();
            $(".Asia").hide();
            $(".Europe").hide();
            $(".NAmerica").hide();
            $(".Oceania").hide();
            $(".SAmerica").hide();
        }
        .
        .
        .
      });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is that my list of filters may increase and I don't want to have to re-type the `show` and `hide` filters every time I add a filter option. Is there a way to make sure that when I select `Europe`, only countries that have Europe in their `class` are shown and anything else is hidden? or do I have to copy paste the `if ... else` statement every single time? I know right now its only 7 items but it could up to 50.

Comment: Maybe `not`-selector will help you.

Comment: i usually add an extra class, say "country". Then set your values = to the country name. Then your function should start with $(".country").hide(), then $("."+this.value).show().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a continents object that acts like a dictionary. Then show all of the `.body-location`s. Then, hide anything that isn't the selected continent.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var continents = {
        1: 'Africa',
        2: 'Asia',
        ... // Add continents as necessary
    };

    $('#country-filter').on('change', function() {
        // Show all of your locations
        $('.body_location').show();

        // If this.value == 0, we want to show everything.
        if (this.value > 0) {
            // Hide anything that isn't the selected continent.
            $('.body_location:not(.' + continents[this.value] + ')').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with out needing to change your `html`

```
$('#country-filter').on('change', function() {
    var filter_class = '.' + $('#country-filter option:selected').text();
    $(filter_class).show();
    $('.body_location:not(' + filter_class + ')').hide();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with the situation when `this.value  === 0`. The OP wants everything to be shown in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a lot of code reuse that you could benefit from.

For starters, you might want to create a method such as:

```
showCountriesFromContinent(continent){
  //hide all countries
  $('.country').hide();
  //show only the one you want.
  $(continent).show();
}
```

This assumes you are adding a *.country* class to all your countries, in addition to the specific continent class.

You could eventually have an object of this sort (which I agree might not be the best solution, but I don't have the rest of the context of your application):

```
continents: {
   "1": ".Africa",
   "2": ".Asia",
   "3": ".America"
   ...
}
```

Then a resulting code might look like this:

```
showCountriesFromContinent(continent){
  if(continent == '0')
      $('.country').show();
  else {
      //hide all
      $('.country').hide();
      //show only the one you want.
      $(continents[continent]).show();
  }
}
```

This allows you to add the continents/counties/whatever in just one place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("article.location").hide();
$("#filt_country").on("change", function() {
    If($(this).val()==0) {
         $("article.location").show();
         return false;
    }
    var getText = $("#filt_country option:selected").text();
    $("article.location").hide();
    $("article.location > ."+getText).parent().show();
});
```

this could surely be helpful for you.

Comment: This doesn't deal with the situation when `this.value === 0`. The OP wants everything to be shown in that case.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

```
$('#country-filter').on('change', function() {        
            $(".Africa").toggle(this.value === '0');
            $(".Antartica").toggle(this.value === '1');
            $(".Asia").toggle(this.value === '2');
            $(".Europe").toggle(this.value === '3');
            $(".NAmerica").toggle(this.value === '4');
            $(".Oceania").toggle(this.value === '5');
            $(".SAmerica").toggle(this.value === '6');
//...
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem as he will need to update this script everytime he adds a new category

Comment: When he adds a **new continent** he has to modify his HTML and probably a number of other things on his site. Adding a line to toggle its visibility isn't (arguably) as difficult as ensuring that the Filter-Item text matches the CSS class being selected.